# aws s3 cp multiple files in one command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am copying multiple files to s3 using one command

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-38-250 ~]$ ls *.rpm
1.rpm
2.rpm
3.rpm
```

how do I copy these 3 rpms in 1 aws cli command?

I tried

```
aws s3 cp *.rpm s3://mybucket1/rpms/
```

I got an error

```
Unknown options: 1.rpm, 2.rpm, 3.rpm,s3://mybucket1/rpms/
```

Comment: Thanks! i got it to work using the sync and cp --recursive answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters):

```
aws s3 cp . s3://mybucket1/rpms/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.rpm"
```

or with `sync`:

```
aws s3 sync . s3://mybucket1/rpms/ --exclude "*" --include "*.rpm"
```